# Default tab option in lightning app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I am very new to lightning. I made one component and put it in a lightning app. Like this

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<c:Screenshow/>
</aura:application>
```

And i am calling this on a click event like this.

```
var navUrl = "/inscor/"+compName+"App.app"+"?releaseId="+releaseId;
```

every thing is working as expected. But default SF header is not coming. 
I have implemented  `force:appHostable` for both component and app but it's still not coming. 
can an one please guide me one this.

Comment: Hi @Manhoar. I think lightning apps are supposed to be full screen. If you want to show the Salesforce header, I recommend you to create a new lightning component tab and embed your lightning component `Screenshow` inside.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your quick reply. I am also passing one id to my component. Is it possible ? like that way...

Comment: Unfortunately, I just tested it and url parameters are not accessible from the embeded component inside the tab. Could you give us some details about the redirection you make? What is the page which is calling the redirection? Because you could use the [force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToComponent.htm) event.

Comment: Hi Martin, when i try to to use force:navigateToComponent . I am redirecting to   the same component. Not sure why.
var newEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
            newEvent.setParams({
                componentDef: '"c:'+compName+'"',
                componentAttributes: {
                    releaseId : releaseId
                }
            });
            console.log('compName::'+compName); // getting Name 
            newEvent.fire();

I am calling different component based on some conditions. what's why i used  compName(string var).

Comment: Hi Martin,  can i make one page instead of lightning app. Then it will show the  tabs. But is it possible to get url parameters from page to lightning component ?

Comment: It would be best if you will post all of your code into the question...